# What mean neural network is executed in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

TensorFlow graph API separates graph construction and execution. Because of this, I can't understand in which line neural network is executed.

```
"""
- model_fn: function that performs the forward pass of the model
- init_fn: function that initializes the parameters of the model.
- learning_rate: the learning rate to use for SGD.
"""
tf.reset_default_graph()
is_training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name='is_training')

with tf.device(device):
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 32, 32, 3])
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
    params = init_fn()           # Initialize the model parameters
    scores = model_fn(x, params) # Forward pass of the model
    loss = training_step(scores, y, params, learning_rate) # SGD

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for t, (x_np, y_np) in enumerate(train_dset):

        feed_dict = {x: x_np, y: y_np}
        loss_np = sess.run(loss, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

As described in the Tensorflow documentation: (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#run)

> This method runs one "step" of TensorFlow computation, by running the
>   necessary graph fragment to execute every Operation and evaluate every
>   Tensor

In you example, `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` run the initilization operation that create all the weights and tensors, `loss_np = sess.run(loss, feed_dict=feed_dict)` executes all the operations up to `loss`.

I hope this answers your question